# Prove Nowhere continuous function

Tags: calculus

I have a question as following. For what values of $x$ is  $f$ continuous ?

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x \in \mathbb{Q} \\ 1 & x \notin \mathbb{Q} \end{cases} $$

Now, I claim that this is nowhere continuous function. I set out to prove this the following way. If $f$ is continuous at some point $a \in \mathbb{R}$, then we have that

$$ \lim \limits_{x \to a} f(x) = f(a) $$

But, $f(x)$ is defined at all points. So,$f$ would not be continuous if limit does not exist. So, I make a proof by contradiction here. I assume that the limit is defined. So, I assume that

$$ \lim \limits_{x \to a} f(x) = L $$

for some $L \in \mathbb{R} $. This means, using epsilon delta definition that,

$$ \forall \varepsilon> 0\; \exists \delta >0\;\forall x \in D \;\big( 0 < |x-a| < \delta \implies |f(x) -L| < \varepsilon \big) $$

where $D$ is the domain for $x$. In this case, its same as $\mathbb{R}$. Now, I do transformation here. Let $h = x-a$. With this the limit becomes

$$ \lim \limits_{h \to 0} f(a + h) = L $$

and epsilon-delta definition becomes

$$ \forall \varepsilon> 0\; \exists \delta >0\;\forall h \in \mathbb{R} \;\big( 0 < |h| < \delta \implies |f(a + h) -L| < \varepsilon \big) \cdots\cdots (1)$$

Now, I will make two cases here.

Case 1)  $a \in \mathbb{Q}$

Now, in equation 1, choosing, $\varepsilon = 1/2$, I get that there is some $\delta > 0$ such that

$$ \forall h \in \mathbb{R} \;\Bigl( 0 < |h| < \delta \implies |f(a + h) -L| < \frac{1}{2} \Bigr) $$

Since, $\delta > 0$, $\exists \; y \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $ 0 < y < \delta$. This follows from density of rationals. So, we have $ 0 < |y| < \delta$. So, using universal instantiation and Modus ponens, I get

$$ |f(a + y) -L| < \frac{1}{2}  $$

Since $a \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $y \in \mathbb{Q}$, it follows that $a + y \in \mathbb{Q}$ since rationals are closed under addition. So, $ f(a+y) = 0 $. It follows that

$$ |L| < \frac{1}{2}  \cdots\cdots(2) $$

Also, since $\delta > 0$, $\exists \; z \notin \mathbb{Q}$ such that $ 0 < z < \delta$. This follows from density of irrationals. So, we have $ 0 < |z| < \delta$. Also $z \in \mathbb{R}$. So, using universal instantiation and Modus ponens, I get

$$ |f(a + z) -L| < \frac{1}{2}  $$

Since $a \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $z \notin \mathbb{Q}$. So, $a + z \notin \mathbb{Q}$. And, $f(a+z) = 1$. It follows that

$$ |L - 1| < \frac{1}{2}  \cdots\cdots(3) $$

Using inequalities 2 and 3, I conclude that $L < L$ , which is a contradiction. So, my initial assumption that the limit exists is wrong. Now, I move to the case 2

Case 2) $a \notin \mathbb{Q}$

This follows similar reasoning as the case 1 and I again reach the same contradiction $L < L$.
Since I reach contradictions in both cases, it means that the limit does not exist at any $a \in \mathbb{R}$. This means that function is not continuous at any point in $\mathbb{R}$.

Is the proof correct ?

Thanks

Comment: I can approve the result is that it is nowhere continous because both the rationals and the irrationals are dense in $\mathbb R$

Comment: @Peter, so is my reasoning correct here?

Comment: @Peter I am checking the proof, so I'll respond to the OP, thanks for informing me.

Comment: It is difficult to follow.  If $\epsilon <1$ then for any $\delta >0$ there are points $y$ with $|x-y|<\delta$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|>\epsilon$

Comment: @Henry. Ok, your argument too is good. Thanks. I think my proof is correct